# PHP: Unable to keep some entries blank

Tags: php, mysql

I have created simple PHP form which includes entries of double, date and varchar values.
It worked just fine on localhost and the user could input some entries, leaving the others blank. But on server data entry is successful only when all values are entered. 
In MySQL, the records can take null value but still, there is the following error:

```
Incorrect double value: '' for column 'birthweight' at row 1
                             or 

Incorrect double value: '' for column 'date' at row 1
```

My form looks like this:

```
<tr>
                <td>Birth Weight</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="birthweight"  placeholder=" Enter Birth Weight"> Kg</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Date of Birth</td>
                <td><input type="date" name="DateOfBirth"  name="DateOfBirth" class="Select"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Sex</td>
                <td><select name="sex"  class="Select">
                        <option value ="--"> Select </option>
                          <option value="Male ">Male</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
```

php code:

```
$db = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['DateOfBirth']);
$sx = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['sex']);
$birthwt = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['birthweight']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO tab1 (db, sx, birthwt)
VALUES ('$db', '$sx', '$birthwt')";
```

This is the table in the database:
[image]

Comment: `value="Male "` for one thing, spaces count as value.

Comment: you need to update your question to contain the db schema/values and what's being passed in those inputs.

Comment: From the error messages, it seems obvious. An empty string is not a valid value for a double column. When inserting you need to change an empty value to 0.0 or leave it out of the insert. Anther possibility is to set a default value for that column.

Comment: The default value for the column is already null. And Like I said, it works just fine on local host

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I have edited the question to include a table screenshot

Comment: check for errors then. When something works on one but not another, then that could mean syntax errors. PHP's error reporting is handy to use, and `mysqli_error($link)` on the query. I also don't see where or if you executed the query.

Comment: The thing is if I fill out all fields, data entry is successful. no field can be left blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database was set to strict mode, changed it to NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
 and it worked.

Command in MySQL:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

and to check whether the changes have been made:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
```